# What does the * asterisk mean in a mysql statement?

Tags: mysql

```
Ex. mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id');
```

Comment: It means "all fields (columns)"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: What would something like `Order.select('orders.*')` mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means select all columns in the table.

Answer (score 7):

It means that you are selecting every column in the table. This is something you should avoid in production environments though because it causes a bit of overhead and things tend to break when you alter your tables and use the `*` selector.

A better way to do this is to select only the columns you need each time, like the following example:

```
SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` FROM members WHERE id='$id'
```

Answer (score 4):

Select ALL fields from some table.

Answer (score 4):

It's a wildcard it means return all columns for that table in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

It means "Select All", referring to all columns in referenced table.  The issue with `*` relates to insert statements with existing tables or select statements used in a static report template.  Any change in the referenced table would cause a change in the returned result set using *.  If the insert or report source recordset has any additional or missing columns, the query may break.  The main point is that using `*` can give you inconsistent columns and recordsets.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the answer you've referenced since it doesn't answer the question itself.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I just wanted to give some examples of the issue that I have encountered.  I don't have enough reputation points to post a comment to someone else's answer.

Comment: This is the best answer, since it tells readers why using it is not a golden hammer solution.